# Ambigious type conversion in constructor call

Tags: c++

```
class String {
public:
    String(int n); // allocate n bytes to the String object
    String(const char *p); // initializes object with char *p
};
```

Now the below code

```
String mystring = 'x';
```

This calls the String( int n ) and not String( const char* ).
Why is there a type conversion happening even when I pass a const char* ? I know a explicit solves this issue but why is the type conversion happening in the first place even when I pass the correct type ?

Comment: Maybe it isn't the "correct type".

Comment: What did you expect? An implicit conversion of a non-pointer type to a pointer? I can't think of any reasonable conversion or assumption here. Edit: Oh, wait, you thought `'x'` was a `char const *`. No, that's `"x"`, which is a `char const[]`, which implicitly converts to a `char const *`. Flagging as typo, in that case!

Comment: Gotcha. Please, provide this as an answer and I shall accept it.

Comment: @KodeWarrior I think the existing answers already covered this in enough detail (which isn't much, given how simple it is), so unless there's anything in particular you think is missing from those, I don't want to steal any thunder... and if you feel something is missing, you could comment and ask those users to elaborate so that they might make their answers seem accept-worthy to you.

Comment: @underscore_d your score is much lesser. Given that you provided a satisfactory answer, I thought I'll award your points. It's okay if u don't want it :)

Comment: @KodeWarrior That's kind of you, but really it's about quality of answers, not redistributing rep points, and I'm not sure I had much to add... and am too late anyway. Maybe next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing a `const char *`. You are passing a `char`.

You meant to write:

```
String mystring = "x";
```

Answer (score 2):

`'x'` is of type `char`, `char` to `int` is a better conversion than `char` to `const char*`. Use double quotes to create a string literal.

Comment: `char` to `const char*` is not a valid conversion (which is not clear from your answer).